# Angular ngFor dynamic property

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    <mat-select placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [compareWith]="compareValues" (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
      <mat-option #matOption *ngFor="let item of itemsList | async" [value]="item['{{value}}']">
        {{item.Name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

> item['{{value}}']

How to bind a dynamic property to ngFor. For example: 
I want to bind item.Name in one moment, but item.Value in different situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some more ways I guess, but I usually do the following:

```
<option *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" [value]="option[this.field]">
  Option {{i}}
</option>
```

*`this` keyword can be excluded in most versions of Angular, but may be not in older ones. Tested with Angular 6, and it works fine without `this` keyword: `[value]="option[field]"`.*

Pay attention, that you don't really need interpolation, here I just take an `option` object and read the specific key, which is stored as a string in `field` class property. For example, if `field` class property has a `'qwerty'` value, that part of HTML equals to `[value]="option['qwerty']"`, and the binding will change when the value changes.

Here is a working [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-a24jxv?file=src/app/app.component.html), you can check a console and ensure, that the binding changes dynamically.

Comment: is `this` in `this .field` needed?

Comment: @ABOS in Angular 6 it's not necessary, but I'm not sure about older versions. You can try to remove `this` in your Angular version, and in most cases, it will work.

Comment: @ Commercial Suicide, do you know why angular interpret option.field and option[field] differently in some cases? It seems angular always interprets option.field as a static field.

Comment: @ABOS Can't really answer what's going on under the hood, but it's a good question. I'm just using bracket notation when trying to access class properties from a template since started using Angular 2+.

Comment: @ Commercial Suicide, I think I made a silly mistake, option.field should correspond to option['field'], not option[field] :)

Comment: @ABOS Maybe in your case it should, but in my answer it shouldn't, because we want to use a value from the `field` class property, and not just get value from `option['field']`. `option.field === option['field']`, but `option.field !== option[field]`

Comment: @ABOS, *do you know why angular interpret option.field and option[field] differently in some cases?* Actually, yes. `option.field` looks for a property "field" in the object "option", but `option[field]` looks for a property, which name is stored in `field` variable. I don't know, why I didn't answer immediately.

Answer (score -2):

You can make a condition if you have some variable that told you when you want to use each one of them for example:

```
{{Item.UseName ? Item.Name : Item.Vaule }}
```